# Restore top panel in NetBeans

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans for my work. Suddenly top panel disappeared from all windows. I'm talking about panel where you can switch between current source and local history. See screenshot for better understanding: http://i62.tinypic.com/v8hdnp.png

As you can see i'm using latest stable version of NetBeans. Do i accidentally pressed some key combination that removed that panel or this is a bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Right click on line numbers panel and then check "Show Editor Toolbar" option.

http://i58.tinypic.com/332c61g.png